# Get next and previous ACF field to current

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields

I have a ACF loop for slick slider. I am trying to get the previous and next slide title to the current.

```
<?php if (have_rows('videofeed','option')): ?>
<div class="slider-popular">
            <?php while (have_rows('videofeed2','option')) : the_row(); ?>
                <div class="slider-go-wrap slick-current">
                      <h2 class="video-title"> <?php the_sub_field('video_title'); ?> </h2><!-- the video title -->

                    <div class="video-controls">
                                <div class="prev-title-popular">
                                    <span class="controltitles prev-videotitle">PREVIOUS TITLE HERE <?php the_sub_field('video_title'); ?></span> <!-- previous  ACF row sub_field "video_title" here -->
                                </div>

                                <div class="next-title-popular">
                                    <span class="controltitles next-videotitle">NEXT TITLE HERE <?php the_sub_field('video_title'); ?></span><!-- next ACF row sub_field "video_title" here -->
                                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile;?>
</div>     
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have grasp of using jQuery for doing this but can not seem to get this to work. At the moment I'm at something like the following:

```
$('.slider-go-wrap').each(function() {
  currentSlide = $('.slick-current');
   nextSlide = currentSlide.next();
   prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

   nextSlideData = nextSlide.find('.next-videotitle').html();
   prevSlideData = prevSlide.find('.prev-videotitle').html();
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/px2bvdbt/12/

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want next and previous posts?

Comment: It's a slider, so I'd need the ACF field 'video_title' from next and previous rows

Comment: Here's a fiddle. Problem is that it only works with one div but it should work with all slides: https://jsfiddle.net/px2bvdbt/12/